# How to build old Android project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sony

I've found an old git repo.
It's an Android application for Sony System Cameras.

It's for Android SDK 10

The project can be found here:
https://github.com/ma1co/PMCADemo

I'm not able to build it in the newest version of Android Studio. I've added the details to the following issue:
https://github.com/ma1co/PMCADemo/issues/16

I hope that maybe here more people can help me, the repo is updated the last time in 2018.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the command in `versionCode` with a number like 40 and `versionName` with a dummy one & then try to sync the gradle?

Comment: Yes and then I'm just getting another error :/ I can post the result tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the following files, and it is working fine to me (You need to [specify](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) the Gradle plugin according to your android studio version, my version is 3.4)

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Sun Jul 21 00:42:34 IST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

**build.gradle top level**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://jitpack.io"
            }
        }
    }
```

**build.gradle app level**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
//    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.github.ma1co.pmcademo.app"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

//    compileOptions {
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
//    }
}

//android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
//    variant.outputs.each { output ->
//        def apkName = "PMCADemo-${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
//        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, apkName)
//    }
//}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.ma1co.OpenMemories-Framework:framework:-SNAPSHOT'
    compileOnly 'com.github.ma1co.OpenMemories-Framework:stubs:-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.1.1'
}
```

> It is my output

[image]

Comment: I've installed SDK10 and the Gradle build version in the SDK Manager, but no result

Comment: I'm able to build the application too with these changes thanks, but the camera need an Android Application with SDK Version 10. Is there a way to go back to version 10?

Comment: I've just changed the SDKVersions to 10 and the apk is also working on the camera.

Comment: why did you disable the  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" ?